# Layout like Java GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically I want to get a Layout that behaves like a Java GridLayout.

I tried LinearLayout and TableRow but the elements are always added after each other.

Whats the best way to achieve this (using the xml approach)?

Comment: TableRow is part of TableLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/updated-sdk-tools-and-adt-revision-17.html) You can use GridLayout with Support Library

> A new Library Project adds support for GridLayout back to API level 7
>   and higher

Comment: Correct. Just as addendum: the compat version of `GridLayout` is not actually inside the support library, but a separate Android library project you'll need to add as dependency. You can find it in your local sdk folder: `<sdk_folder>\extras\android\compatibility\v7\gridlayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_buttons"
        android:text="@string/sGet" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_buttons"
        android:text="@string/sStop"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_buttons"
        android:text="@string/sSettings"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/main_buttons"
        android:text="@string/sExit"
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```